# Javascript bug, repeated prompts, which only appears in GitHub

Tags: javascript, jquery, github

I have a .html file that works perfectly when I open it directly in my browser, but when I preview an exact copy of that file which sits in its own GitHub repository, then it has a bug.

The bug that appears: After the user clicks the button, the browser (chrome) repeats some simple prompts twice.
(The prompts are on lines 18 and 19 in the GitHub file)

Here is the file on GitHub:
https://github.com/JMurphyWeb/sketch-pad/blob/master/index.html

Here is the buggy web preview using the file from GitHub:
http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/JMurphyWeb/sketch-pad/blob/master/index.html

Comment: Do you mean that your whole script is executed twice, or is it really the single `prompt` call? In what order do they show up when repeated? What debugging have you done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in [htmlpreview.github.io](https://github.com/htmlpreview/htmlpreview.github.com), it injects your whole script twice. This means that the button click listener is also attached two times, and of course the prompts also appear twice then.

You can instead use http://rawgit.com/JMurphyWeb/sketch-pad/master/index.html